# How to handle multiple query routes in one component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, mean-stack, angular-routing

I am currently using Angular@9.1.3 and I want to know if we can handle multiple query routes pointing towards a single component.

For Example: I have a default route `http://localhost:4200/main` and I want to handle two queries in this route that are `http://localhost:4200/main?option=option-1` and `http://localhost:4200/main?Country=US&id=1`. Since both the routes points to same default route how can I handle this is in main.component.ts separately?

Here's the code for main.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params.id;
      this.country = params.country;// Here I have only handled the second route which has country=US
                                    // query but how can I also handle option=option-1 query which
                                    // will be a separate query?
      console.log(params);
      this.dummyFun(this.country, this.id);
    } );
  }
```

Is there any way I can target a particular section of code that will handle both query separately?

I can use multiple if-else but I think that would complicate this.

Comment: i think for such small code, `if-else` should be fine.  Can you explain the scope of how the code might grow in future ? There are design practices to eliminate if else (you can find on google) , but make sure you dont do an overkill if the code is not meant to grow 
 at that scale.

Comment: basically I have 3 fields, two of them are `select` in one of them is an `input` field. As of now I am using if-else. But can I target each query independently without if-else?